# Cloud9 to server (Want to publish)

Tags: laravel, ssh, cloud9

Have coded webpages on Cloud9(Laravel installed. Not AWS but https://c9.io) and now want to publish pages. I already have spaces in rental server to deploy but don't know transfer data from cloud9 to server nor how to setup server.

Please let me know if you know how to transfer data and setup server. Also welcome share URLs that explain these FAQ. Thank you in advance.

(Googled these keywords but not found any useful expalnation. Keywords:ssh,ftp,laravel,cloud9)

Answer (score 0):

Found solution from my tutor advices. Downloaded files from cloud9 and transfered to server by FileZilla. While doing this, have to modified some files to be adopted to server but it was not a big deal.
Now I think I have to use AWS cloud9 or similar services to deploy works more easily.
Hope this comment help somebody stacked.